# Setting the internal array pointer without iterating in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to set PHP's internal array pointer without first iterating through the array. Take the following dummy code as example:

```
$array = range(1, 100);

// Represents the array key
$pointer = 66;

set_array_pointer($pointer, $array);

$nextValue = next($array); // Should return 68
```

Comment: `$pointer` is meant to hold the key or the value? Personally I don't think there's a PHP way of making the array pointer jump to a location and some sort of looping will be involved.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for `pointing` that out to me :)

Comment: Basically all those functions (next/prev/current/key) only really make sense when you are doing some kind of looping over that data anyway …

Comment: Some tips here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-can-you-move-an-array-pointer-to-a-specific-key/29027/6

Comment: Why would you want this? Array pointers don't go through the array the same way as the order of the array would make you think. Consider `$a = array(); $a[1] = 1; $a[0] = 0; echo end($a);` printing `0`, though you might expect the end of the numeric array to contain `1` ... So until your motives are clear, it could be you are wanting to implement something useless.

Comment: I'm not sure what;s the purpose of this, but here is possible solution without iterating, how ever I don't know about the performance
`$input = range(1, 100);
$output = array_slice($input, 66);
next($output)`

Comment: My motives are purely based on intellectual curiosity..

Comment: does your intellectual curiosity only concern loops in userland or also the internal handling of php? The answer by LibertyPaul has a way of setting the pointer without you triggering a loop in userland, but php will internally loop through the array when calling $iterator->seek() (at least as my limited c knowledge tells me here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_array.c#L1347)

Comment: @Jojo Thanks for the info. I figured it would still iterate through the array that way :D

Comment: that makes me feel as there is no way of accomplishing a pointer set to a position without looping through the array ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution LibertyPaul provided using [ArrayIterator::seek](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.seek.php) seems to be the only way to make php set a pointer to a position within an array without initializing looping in userland. 
php will internally loop through the array to set the pointer, though, as you can read from the php [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_array.c#L1347) of ArrayIterator::seek():

```
/* {{{ proto void ArrayIterator::seek(int $position)
   Seek to position. */
SPL_METHOD(Array, seek)
{
    zend_long opos, position;
    zval *object = getThis();
    spl_array_object *intern = Z_SPLARRAY_P(object);
    HashTable *aht = spl_array_get_hash_table(intern);
    int result;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "l", &position) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    if (!aht) {
        php_error_docref(NULL, E_NOTICE, "Array was modified outside object and is no longer an array");
        return;
    }

    opos = position;

    if (position >= 0) { /* negative values are not supported */
        spl_array_rewind(intern);
        result = SUCCESS;

        while (position-- > 0 && (result = spl_array_next(intern)) == SUCCESS);

        if (result == SUCCESS && zend_hash_has_more_elements_ex(aht, spl_array_get_pos_ptr(aht, intern)) == SUCCESS) {
            return; /* ok */
        }
    }
    zend_throw_exception_ex(spl_ce_OutOfBoundsException, 0, "Seek position %pd is out of range", opos);
} /* }}} */
```

So it looks like there is no way to set an array-pointer to a certain position without looping through the array

Comment: So it seems that the best answer, however disapointing is no. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with `ArrayObject` and `ArrayIterator`:

```
$array = range(1, 100);
$pointer = 66;

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();
$iterator->seek($pointer);     //set position
$iterator->next();             // move iterator
$nextValue = $iterator->current();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can define your own function using next() and reset() to use pointer and use like below code

```
<?php
function findnext (&$array,$key) { 
   reset ($array); 
   while (key($array) !== $key) { 
     if (next($array) === false) throw new Exception('can not find key'); 
   } 
} 

$array = range(1, 100);
$pointer = 66;

findnext($array,$pointer); 
echo next($array); //this will give 68
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set actual `pointer` for array. `php` already has support for [internal array pointers see next() method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php):

```
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
$mode = current($transport); // $mode = 'foot';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = next($transport);    // $mode = 'car';
$mode = prev($transport);    // $mode = 'bike';
$mode = end($transport);     // $mode = 'plane';
```