# Getting the next value in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the next value in a PHP array for example:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$current_array_val = 'c';
//so I want to run a code to get the next value in the array and
$next_array_val = 'd';
//And also another code to get the previous value which will be
$prev_array_val = 'b';
```

Please how do I run my code to achieve this

Comment: Take a closer look at [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719268/setting-the-internal-array-pointer-without-iterating-in-php) for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-search.php

```
$index = array_search($current_array_val, $array);
if($index !== false && $index > 0 ) $prev = $array[$index-1];
if($index !== false && $index < count($array)-1) $next = $array[$index+1];
```

Comment: See my answer with the array_flip() method for if you are dealing with large arrays (array_search() can become comparatively very slow with large datasets).

Answer (score 5):

use [next()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.next.php) function:

In addition: use current() or prev()

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

$current= current($array); // 'a'
$nextVal = next($array); // 'b'
$nextVal = next($array); // 'c'

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are another solution,

```
$values = array_values($array);
$search=array_search($current_array_val,$values);
$next=$values[(1+$search)%count($values)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

$flipped_array = array_flip($array);

$middle_letter = 'c'; //Select your middle letter here

$index_of_middle_letter = $flipped_array[$middle_letter];

$next_index = $index_of_middle_letter + 1;
$prev_index = $index_of_middle_letter - 1;
$next_item = $array[$next_index];
$prev_item = $array[$prev_index];
```

array_search() is slower than doing an array_flip() when it comes to dealing with large arrays. The method I have described above is *far* more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_search, and increment/decrement for next/prev item in array.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$current_array_val = array_search('c', $array);
//so I want to run a code to get the next value in the array and
$next_array_val = $array[$current_array_val+1];
//And also another code to get the previous value which will be
$prev_array_val = $array[$current_array_val-1];


echo $next_array_val; // print d
echo $prev_array_val; // print b
```

Comment: array_search is slower than doing an array_flip (which indexes the values) when it comes to dealing with large arrays.

Comment: okok, thanks for tips, i'm not a pro php, just tying to help some people and learn by reading other answer

Comment: No problem, brother! Nothing wrong with your method when it comes to small sample sets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code sample for a better understanding of the object-oriented way of navigating through arrays:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');

$pointer = 'c';

// Create new iterator
$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

$iterator->seek($pointer);     //set position

// Go to the next value
$iterator->next();             // move iterator 

// Assign next value to a variable
$nextValue = $iterator->current();
```