# How to find array next value based on current value

Tags: php, arrays

I have array as below-

```
Array
(
   [1] => admin
   [5d1acff7-51f5-d10a-8807-5ce3a25f3f01] => atul
   [9324e078-e651-09ab-856c-5d00cf1d6302] => tushar
   [3e4d9711-e4e0-f9de-8d40-5d021f3137fb] => praful
   [b283b589-c527-389f-498b-5cf0ea2338e1] => suraj

)
```

Here I cant find the next value based on key,so I want to find next value based on current value.
Suppose I have current value is 'atul' now I want next value as 'tushar' with its key.

Comment: When you say the *current value*, is this as part of a loop or just a value entered somehow?

Comment: its just value stored in a variable.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes all values are unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the next value in a php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591894/getting-the-next-value-in-a-php-array)

Comment: That duplicate doesn't deal with associative arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the offset of the search string, increment it, then access the key and value from the isolated element.

**Checking for a `false` boolean result from `array_search()` is critical.  Otherwise incrementing `false` becomes `1`, and then you have an incorrect script.**

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cmPpB)) ([or var_export the element](https://3v4l.org/AHOek))

```
$array = [
   1 => 'admin',
   '5d1acff7-51f5-d10a-8807-5ce3a25f3f01' => 'atul',
   '9324e078-e651-09ab-856c-5d00cf1d6302' => 'tushar',
   '3e4d9711-e4e0-f9de-8d40-5d021f3137fb' => 'praful',
   'b283b589-c527-389f-498b-5cf0ea2338e1' => 'suraj'
];

$values = array_values($array);
$offset = array_search('atul', $values);

if ($offset !== false && isset($values[++$offset])) {
    $element = array_slice($array, $offset, 1, true);
    echo key($element) , " : " , current($element);
} else {
    echo "not found or no next";
}
```

Output:

```
9324e078-e651-09ab-856c-5d00cf1d6302 : tushar
```